# Function returns value without replacing the variable with the given parameter

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, currying, lambda-calculus

sry about the stupid way I phrased the question here's some explanation: I am experimenting with lambda-calculus in javascript and I am having some minor difficulties. (you don't have to know anything about lambda-calculus to help me)

I have this function (the church numeral 1 btw):

```
function num1(c) {
return function(x){
    return c(x);
}
 }

alert(num1)
```

Behaves as expected and gives the exact same thing as above.

```
alert(num1(num1))
```

Behaves unexpected and gives:

```
function (x) {
    return c(x);
}
```

Why doesn't the javascript replace the 'c' with the function num1? but

```
alert(num1(num1)(num1))
```

Gives:

```
function (x) {
    return c(x);
}
```

And shows that the first c was in fact replaced by the function as it was supposed to.
If the 'c' would not have been replaced, then this would have happened:

```
(num1(num1)(num1))=

(function (x) {return c(x);}(num1=

c(function num1(c) {
    return function(x){
        return c(x);
    }
})
```

So all in all, the code is doing what is it supposed to, but it doesn't output the function with the 'c' replaced. What can I do? Later, I will more functions and then I wont be I able to tell `num1(asd)` and `num1(jkl)` apart because the 'c' doesn't get replaced.

Thank you very much for your help!

Someonelse

Comment: Looks like you are trying to grasp `Y-combinatorial`...

Comment: I know the Y-combinator and how it works (but not why ;) ) and i can use it on paper. I dont know yet what I actually want to do in the end with the js, but this example is just a simplification of my actual problem: the S- and K-Combinator excibit the same stupid behaviour.

Comment: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) will tell you all about how to format the code in your questions.

Comment: You're expecting to see results that really have nothing to do with the way JavaScript actually works. When you pass a function to "alert", it just gives you the string value of the function as it was defined. It makes no attempt to show you how closure variables are bound.

Comment: Do you mean that logging the function shows the "wrong" source code? That's expected - JavaScript doesn't change your source code. In fact, source code doesn't define how execution will behave.

Comment: @Pointy actually theres nothing about formatting code in your link unless im too stupid to see it.
Of course javascript behaves correctly, so my actual question is how can **I** make javascript show me how closure variables are bound?

Comment: Completely normal : http://jsfiddle.net/KByXw/

Comment: @someonelse the only way to do it is to have your own code to do so.  I provided a simple approach in my answer. There's no way to access closure variables from "outside" if there's no code that explicitly exposes the values.

Comment: @someonelse: Alternatively, you could use a debugger. Put a breakpoint on the `return c(x);` line, execute `num1(num1)` and evaluate `c` to see that `c` refers to `num1`.

Comment: @someonelse you're right; I don't know why that wouldn't be in the FAQ.  But you can click the orange question mark above the textarea while typing a question, and that'll lead you to the docs.  The little clickable widgets above the textarea while typing a question or answer are also handy, in particular the "{}" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
function num1(c) {
   function rv(x){
    return c(x);
  }
   rv.showBinding = function() {
     return c;
   }

   return rv;

}
```

Then:

```
alert(num1);
alert(num1(num1).showBinding());
```